# How can i check if the password i add to the textbox, is same as the password in database using mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, model-view-controller

I have a login form where all of the user's data are displayed when you click the login button. When the data are displayed in the form fields, I have an old password, new password and confirm password field, where the user can change his password. Now, when the user puts his old password, I want to check if it is the same password as the password stored in database.

This is how I get the data from database :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id, UpdateModel updatemodel)
    {
        id = 1;
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("@")

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
           "Select Username , Password From BS_Users Where IDBS_Persons=" + id, cn);

        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr1.Read())
        { 
            updatemodel.Username = dr1["Username"].ToString();
            updatemodel.Password = dr1["Password"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            dr.Close();
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();
        return View(updatemodel);
    }
```

and this is how I post them :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UpdateModel p, FormCollection form, int? id)
    {
        id = 1;
        SmartFinanceContext db = new SmartFinanceContext();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {          
            int users = p.UpdateUser(p.Username, Crypto.Hash(p.Password), id = 1);  
            if (_records > 0 && users > 0)
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Home");
            }

            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Can Not Update");
            }
        }
        return View(p);
    }
```

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: when it checks if the passwords are the same then it should let the user to change the password in the "new password " field

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
//Get from database, which would be an encrypted string
var pw = dr1["Password"].ToString();
//Encrypt password sent in by user
var pwCheck = Crypto.Hash(p.Password)

//Check encrypted password from database against encrypted passed-in password
if (pw == pwCheck){
    //do something
}
```